# Get user ID from front controller

Tags: php, controller

I'm looking to create my own front controller for a mini project I'm working on. I used someones example that was shared on Stackoverflow which works great but now I'm trying to pass data such as a user ID.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . /front-controller.php [L]
```

**front-controller.php**

```
<?php

switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    case '/users':
        include 'users.php';
        break;
    case '/user/new':
        include 'users-new.php';
        break;
    default:
        include '404.php';
        break;
}
```

What I want to do now is have the value of USERID be passed to users.php as well ($_GET or any other way) from /users/USERID. Does anyone know a good way to approach this?

Comment: `case '/users':` won't match `/users/1234`.  Common way is to use .htaccess and rewrite `/users/new` to `/users?action=new` and `/users/1234` to `/users?id=1234` etc...

Comment: I know... that's why I'm asking if anyone has an approach to make it work and have the ability to pass data such as users IDs.

Comment: `the ability to pass data` : you can do it in the request body, in the URL (GET), in the headers. So it is possible to have user IDs and any other `data` you want. The previous posted comment also suggests ways you can make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the request body, in the URL (GET), in the headers.